# validate second number in java

Tags: java, android

I am creating a math app where the user enters the answer for a question asked .If the question is 3*2 and if the user press 6 then it will evaluate dynamically- used `onClick` function on all buttons .I have a problem if the question is 5*2 the answer is 10 when the user enters 1 it starts evaluating and shows a wrong answer without waiting for second number.How can I solve this issue .The program has to wait for second number if the answer is in two digits

```
  public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view.getId()==R.id.btn_one ||view.getId()==R.id.btn_two || view.getId()==R.id.btn_three || view.getId()==R.id.btn_four || view.getId()==R.id.btn_five || view.getId()==R.id.btn_six || view.getId()==R.id.btn_seven || view.getId()==R.id.btn_eight || view.getId()==R.id.btn_nine || view.getId()==R.id.btn_zero ||view.getId()== R.id.answer)
    {

        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //get number from tag
        int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

        //either first or subsequent digit

   if(answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
          answerTxt.setText("= "+enteredNum);

       else
         answerTxt.append(""+enteredNum);
        String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
        if(!answerContent.endsWith("?"))
        {
            int enteredAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
            if(enteredAnswer == answer1)
            {
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else{
                response.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
                response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            selectQuestion();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is more: What if the question is "10 * 10"? The answer then has 3 digits. So, you need a more general solution. One idea: Have another button - e.g. "OK" - that the user must click on _after_ entering the answer. The evaluation only starts when clicking that button. Having said this, your question is a little too broad.

Comment: Either you need to have submit/enter button which user has to press once he is finished with the answer or keep some buffer time (for ex: 3 sec) before you show the validated result, so that the buffer time allows user to press the next digit. show only the last result to the user after the buffer time

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be that, instead of using `keyboard` for input; you can dynamically generate 4 buttons (or any number of buttons on your choice) and have the options for answers embossed on them.

The user would be asked to make a choice by clicking on the desired button and then you can evaluate the answer according. You can have a look at the snippet below for some hints.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button)v;
    int answer = Interger.valueOf(button.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perform this operation on button click.

1. Add new button `calculateButton` in `onCreate()`.

   ```
   Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
   calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
           int enteredNum1 = Integer.parseInt(etText1.getText().toString());
           int enteredNum2 = Integer.parseInt(etText2.getText().toString());
           int result = enteredNum1 * enteredNum2;        
       }
    });
   ```

Comment: This solution had already been suggested in the comments. Just adding code to it does not make it an answer.